# Mapping of URIs to files

Tags: modelica

I'm trying to understand mapping of URIs to files. Let's take this URI:

`modelica://foo.bar/file.png`

Is it correct that there are two possible locations for `file.png`?

It could be either

`$MODELICAPATH/foo/file.png` if file `$MODELICAPATH/foo/bar.mo` exists.

Or

`$MODELICAPATH/foo/bar/file.png` if file `$MODELICAPATH/foo/bar/package.mo` exists.

Answer (score 2):

Likely Section "13.2.3 External resources" of the [Modelica Language Specification](https://modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec34.pdf) helps.

A little modification of your example should help to understand how it works. Using `modelica://foo/bar/file.png` refers to `foo` as top-level package/library. The library the path is resolved when it is loaded in the simulation environment. In case you store the library hierarchically (i.e. every package is represented as folder, each model is a file) `bar` would be a subfolder within the libraries root directory. `file.png` would be the file name within `bar`.

This is different if the package is stored as a single file, but as this has several disadvantages I would recommend to go with the hierarchical option.

No need to edit `$ModelicaPath$` if the library is loaded.

Usually pictures etc. are put into a Resources folder within the library. This folder can contain additional folders like `data`, `Images`, `Scripts`...

Comment: Does this mean that my interpretation of the example given above is correct? I'm not writing a package but a documentation browser and need to resolve all kinds of links correctly.

Comment: It can be the second variant even if foo/bar/package.mo does not exist (as stated in the link).
It cannot realistically be the first variant above - since modelica://foo/file.png should refer to a different file.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand it. I'm totally confused. The specification says, that the path is to be interpreted relative to the package. I understood this as: If class `foo.bar` is stored in `foo/bar.mo` then `file.png` must be relative to the path `foo/`, which is `foo/file.png`. But if `foo.bar` is stored in `foo/bar/package.mo` then it is relative to `foo/bar/`, i.e. `foo/bar/file.png`. Where's the mistake in this interpretation?

Comment: The "relative to the package" text is a bit unclear - but the rest of the text makes it clear that if foo.bar is stored in foo/package.mo then modelica//foo.bar/file.png can still be stored as foo/bar/file.png and cannot be stored as foo/file.png since that would collide with modelica://foo/file.png. As MarkusA wrote a better idea is to use a Resources-folder.

Comment: So "relative to the package" means "relative to the top-level directory of the package", where the word package here has nothing to do with the keyword package.

Comment: The last paragraph in 13.2.3 says that `modelica://Modelica/Mechanics/C.jpg` is illegal. Why?

Comment: I think `modelica://Modelica/Mechanics/C.jpg` is legal as this package is a mixture of hierarchical and single file structure. Mechanics as well as MultiBody is hierarchical, whereas Rotational, Translational are stored as single file.

Comment: I guess it is legal, but it might not exist in the same folder as the Mechanics package (if the package was restructured, put in a database, etc). The recommendation is to put everything in the Resources folder on top-level of the package, and all these problems go away.